# parsing/extracting data from a text file. Unable to make it work

Tags: python, parsing

I have a file which I'm trying to extract information from, the file has the information in it and is in a neat line by line format, the information is separated by commas.

I want to put it in a list, or do whatever I can to extract information from a specific index.  The file is huge with over 1000000000 lines, I have to extract the same index in every line in order to get the same piece of information.  These are HASHES I want from the files so I was wondering how I'd find all the occurrences of hashes based on length.

```
import os

os.chdir('C:\HashFiles')

f = open('Part1.txt','r')

file_contents=f.readlines()

def linesA():

for line in file_contents:
    lista = line.split(',')

print linesA()
```

this is all I have so far and this just puts everything in a list which I can index from, but I want to output the data from those indexes to another file and I am unable to because of the for statement, how can I get around this?

Wow you guys are great, now I have a problem because in the file where this info is stored it starts with information about the sponsor who provided the information, how do I bypass those lines to start from another line since the lines I need start at about 100 lines down the file, to help me because at the moment I get an index error and am unable to figure out how to set a condition to counter it. I tried this condition but didnt work : if line[:] != 15: continue

Most recent code to work with:

import csv

```
with open('c:/HashFiles/search_engine_primary.sql') as inf, open('c:/HashFiles/hashes.txt','w') as outf:
for i in xrange(47):
    inf.next()       # skip a line

for line in inf:
    data = line.split(',')
    if str(line[0]) == 'GO':
        continue
    hash = data[15]
    outf.write(hash + '\n')
```

Comment: Some sample input data (and desired output format) would be helpful

Comment: You may want to try the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples).

Comment: INSERT INTO [search_engine_primary] ([MD5], [SHA_1], [SHA_256], [Fuzzy_Hash], [Fuzzy_Block], [Header_HEX], [128_Bytes_ASCII], [Signature], [Logical_Size], [Extraneous], [Encrypted], [NSRL], [key_field]) VALUES (N'00000040f69913a27ff7401  <--only part of it
-------------------------------------------------------------Thats sample data its really long rows all I want to extract are the hashes and 2 other things and output them in the same structure row and column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process the file line-by-line, like so:

```
with open('c:/HashFiles/Part1.txt') as inf, open('c:/HashFiles/hashes.txt','w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        data = line.split(',')
        hash = data[4]
        outf.write(hash + '\n')
```

If you want to separate the hashes by length, maybe something like:

```
class HashStorage(object):
    def __init__(self, fname_fmt):
        self.fname_fmt = fname_fmt
        self.hashfile = {}

    def thefile(self, hash):
        hashlen = len(hash)
        try:
            return self.hashfile[hashlen]
        except KeyError:
            newfile = open(self.fname_fmt.format(hashlen), 'w')
            self.hashfile[hashlen] = newfile
            return newfile

    def write(self, hash):
        self.thefile(hash).write(hash + '\n')

    def __del__(self):
        for f in self.hashfiles.itervalues():
            f.close()
        del self.hashfiles

store = HashStorage('c:/HashFiles/hashes{}.txt')

with open('c:/HashFiles/Part1.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        data = line.split(',')
        hash = data[4]
        store.write(hash)
```

**Edit:**: is there any way to identify sponsor lines - for example, they start with "#"? You could filter like

```
with open('c:/HashFiles/Part1.txt') as inf, open('c:/HashFiles/hashes.txt','w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            data = line.split(',')
            hash = data[4]
            outf.write(hash + '\n')
```

otherwise, if you have to skip N lines - this is nasty, because what if the number changes? - you can instead

```
with open('c:/HashFiles/Part1.txt') as inf, open('c:/HashFiles/hashes.txt','w') as outf:
    for i in xrange(N):
        inf.next()       # skip a line

    for line in inf:
        data = line.split(',')
        hash = data[4]
        outf.write(hash + '\n')
```

**Edit2:**

```
with open('c:/HashFiles/search_engine_primary.sql') as inf, open('c:/HashFiles/hashes.txt','w') as outf:
    for i in xrange(47):
        inf.next()       # skip a line

    for line in inf:
        data = line.split(',')
        if len(data) > 15:      # skip any line without enough data items
            hash = data[15]
            outf.write(hash + '\n')
```

Does this still give you errors??

Comment: Wow you guys are great, now I have a problem because in the file where this info is stored it starts with information about the sponsor who provided the information, how do I bypass those lines to start from another line since the lines I need start at about 100 lines down the file, to help me because at the moment I get an index error and am unable to figure out how to set a condition to counter it.   I tried this condition but didnt work :  if line[:] != 15:  continue

Comment: @BrayanHernandez It would be a good idea to add these additional specifications to your original question since not everyone reads all of the comments.

Comment: I tried your skip method but it didn't work for me, I got the error that index didn't exist, I believe it's because they're split by 'GO' every 100 lines, how would I add this as an except, it skips to the line I want, it just cannot continue when it hits a line that only has index[0] in the line.

Comment: @Brayan Hernandez: please post your actual code (the smallest working example that gives the error) and actual error message - otherwise debugging requires a psychic.

Comment: heres what my code looks like. I tried to add the exception for the GO but even without the piece of code I added it didnt work.   ----------------------------------------------------------(ill edit first post with it)-----------import csv



with open('c:/HashFiles/search_engine_primary.sql') as inf, open('c:/HashFiles/hashes.txt','w') as outf:
    for i in xrange(47):
        inf.next()       # skip a line

    for line in inf:
        data = line.split(',')
        if str(line[0]) == 'GO':
            break
        hash = data[15]
        outf.write(hash + '\n')

Comment: the worked beautifully, thank you so much, and the code was so easy to comprehend, thanks again.

Comment: @BrayanHernandez If this answer solved your problem you should [accept it by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to the answer. It'll mark this problem as solved and reward you and the HughBothwell with some rep points.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to process the file line-by-line

```
 with open('Part1.txt') as inf:
      for line in inf:
          # do your processing
          # ... line.split(',') etc...
```

rather than using `readlines()` which reads *all of the data into memory at once*.

Also, depending on what you are doing,  [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) could be helpful in creating your desired output list form the file you are reading.

NOTE: The benefit of using `with` to open the file is that it will *automatically close it* for you when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

**UPDATE**:

To skip the first `N` lines of your input file you can change your code to this:

```
N = 100

with open('Part1.txt') as inf:
     for i, line in enumerate(inf, 1):
         if i < N:   # if line is less than N
            continue # skip the processing
         print line  # process the line
```

I am using [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to automatically generate line numbers. I start this counter at 1 (default is 0 if not specified).

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm happy to correct any errors or improve the answer, but I need some constructive feedback for that. A downvote ***without*** explantion doesn't help OP, SO or me.

Comment: @BrayanHernandez I updated my answer to take your request to skip the first N lines into account

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open(os.path.join('C:\HashFiles','Part1.txt'), 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```